# python - remove string from words in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, string

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#this looks for words in dictionary that begin with 'in' and the suffix is a real word
wordlist = [line.strip() for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words')]
newlist = []
for word in wordlist:
    if word.startswith("in"):
        newlist.append(word)
for word in newlist:
    word = word.split('in')
print newlist
```

how would I get the program to remove the string "in" from all the words that it starts with? right now it does not work

Comment: If you are looking only for words whose opposites are prefixed by "in", note that not all words starting with "in" are opposites of any other words. For example: "intestine", "inject", etc.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well, in those cases, it helps that "testine" and "ject" aren't words (assuming he adds a test for that).  "inquest", however, would be a problem.

Comment: i added a test for that don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` returns a list of the segments obtained by splitting. Furthermore,

```
word = word.split('in')
```

doesn't modify your list, it just modifies the variable being iterated.

Try replacing your second loop with this:

```
for i in range(len(newlist)):
    word = newlist[i].split('in', 1)
    newlist[i] = word[1]
```

Comment: This will have problems with words that include the substring "in" non-prefixally, such as "infinite".

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Look for all words beginning with 'in'
# such that the rest of the word is also
# a valid word.

# load the dictionary:
with open('/usr/share/dict/word') as inf:
    allWords = set(word.strip() for word in inf)  # one word per line
```

1. using 'with' ensures the file is always properly closed;
2. I make allWords a set; this makes searching it an O(1) operation

then we can do

```
# get the remainder of all words beginning with 'in'
inWords = [word[2:] for word in allWords if word.startswith("in")]
# filter to get just those which are valid words
inWords = [word for word in inWords if word in allWords]
```

or run it into a single statement, like

```
inWords = [word for word in (word[2:] for word in allWords if word.startswith("in")) if word in allWords]
```

Doing it the second way also lets us use a generator for the inside loop, reducing memory requirements.

Comment: Your last list comprehension statement is one heck of a tongue twister.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from your question what you want in `newlist` if you just want words that start with "in" but with "in" removed then you can use a [slice](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-slice):

```
newlist = [word[2:] for word in wordlist if word.startswith('in')]
```

If you want words that start with "in" are still in `wordlist` once they've had "in" removed (is that what you meant by "real" in your comment?) then you need something a little different:

```
newlist = [word for word in wordlist if word.startswith('in') and word[2:] in wordlist
```

Note that in Python we use a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list), not an "array".

Comment: This is a great answer.  That second list comprehension will be O(N^2) in length of wordlist, though.  If that's the behavior you want, and wordlist is big, consider a trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `wordlist` is the list of words. Following code should do the trick:

```
for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    if wordlist[i].startswith("in"):
        wordlist[i] = wordlist[i][2:]
```

It is better to use `while` loop if the number of words in the list is quite big.

Comment: do i have to import a module? ltrim does not seem to be an acceptable attribute

Comment: @tekknolagi: I think that's supposed to be `lstrip()`

Comment: yeah, it must be strip sry. Writing in few languages at the same time and messing up method' names sometimes :)

Comment: There is no string.ltrim() method; and if you meant string.lstrip(), it does not do what you think: "abaabbcc".lstrip("ab") -> "cc"

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell: It does the same thing as PHP's `ltrim()` at least. But you're right, not quite what the OP intended.

Comment: @Hugh True, I've modified my solution